# Testing Angular Http services via Jasmine / Karma

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular2-testing

For a series of reasons I would like to be able to test some Http services (not via mock) using Jasmine / Karma support of Angualar.

If I use the following code

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [],
      imports: [
        HttpModule
      ]
    });
    .......
```

tests fail with the following message printed on Karma browser

```
Error: No provider for Http!
Error: DI Error
    at NoProviderError.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?1adeefc4ae1dd1c3f12dac836469652bbacab66c:2054:33)
    at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?5cfdb8c92873c902e956a345863bab75c6324f3e:23292:16)
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?5cfdb8c92873c902e956a345863bab75c6324f3e:47503:16)
    at new NoProviderError (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?5cfdb8c92873c902e956a345863bab75c6324f3e:47565:16)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?5cfdb8c92873c902e956a345863bab75c6324f3e:63961:19)
.......
```

Any suggestion on how to fix it would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You may need to configure the provider for Http. For example:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [ { provide: Http, useClass: Http } ],
```

If that doesn't do the trick, please share your imports and any earlier code in the test spec.